# Using pre-seeding and boot params for completely un-attended Debian install

Tags: debian, boot, system-installation, preseed

I'm trying to use simple-cdd to create an complete unattended install of debian.

I have created a preseed file that gets used - but the installer is still asking me three questions

What is my region or continent?
What is my country?
What is my keyboard?

I have tried combinations of setting the locale in both the profile's conf file and in the preseed file - but these three questions still get asked.

I've seen it hinted that these question must be supplied as boot parameters as the preseed file does not get loaded until these questions are answered.

Is there a way to auto-answer these files?

Answer (score 2):

According to the website http://sources.debian.net/src/simple-cdd/0.5.0/README/ to preseed these answers, you should pass the `--locale` parameter to the `build-simple-cdd` command

```
Language and Country Selection

to pre-select the language and country, it is recommended to use the --locale
commandline option:

 build-simple-cdd --locale en_US
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the debian installer still asks for the keymap - so only 2/3rds solved :-(

Comment: Try `priority=critical` on the kernel command line.

Comment: The current release (stretch) also has a `--keyboard` option